# How to open a browser on a Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: browser, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, file-transfer

**How can I open a browser in my VM instance?** And how safe/unsafe can this be?

The instance is a **Ubuntu 16.04**

The only way I know to access the VM is via the SSH button provided by google on the cloud console website.

I want to use it regularly, with pages visually displayed and mouse clicks. (Treat me as a newbie, I'm totally new on Linux and on VMs. I didn't even know there was another way of controlling the browser)

---

**Context:**

I need to download a huge amount of data from websites to my virtual machine on Google Compute Engine.

I know there are solutions on the web to transfer files from my machine, but my internet really sucks, it's not feasible.

I also know there are some commands like `wget` using copied cookies to download some files.

Even though, I feel I'll be needing to use a browser, especially because I want to use a regular Google Drive interface to transfer my files if I need.

Knowing more about this helps, but the question is "how to open a browser and navigate as if I was a regular newbie, with pages displayed and mouse clicks".

Comment: You can run a headless chrome and there are also zillions of other ways to emulate an actual browser but it's almost certain you won't need to just to download files. Instead of having feelings about it, you should try it and then ask specific questions if you run into any problems.

Comment: My specific question is how to open a browser. The easiest of the zillions of ways will certainly be what I need.

Comment: 'Open a browser' is pretty vague. What operating system? Are you running any kind of GUI? Do you need or want to? What's the programming part of the question? etc

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, I only know how to access it via the SSH button provided by Google on the cloud console website. It doesn't seem like I have a GUI.

Comment: You should put this stuff in your question, as you know. How do you plan to control this browser you've opened? You can also just google around 'headless chrome' (and headless browser in general), 'phantom.js', selenium, etc. Using wget or curl is going to be substantially simpler, though

Comment: I suggest to improve the format of your question to just, how to open a browser in an Ubuntu 16.04 VM in Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Did you find a way to do so?

Comment: Well, I ended up learning how to use the terminal. Using `wget` and some APIs for specific websites. I think you'll only be able to use a browser if you install a graphic interface.

Answer (score 1):

Install the desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Install VNC server

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
sudo apt-get install xinit
```

and then run

```
startx
```

Comment: Got this at `startx`: `Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/danielmoller/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information
.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.`

Comment: change the tty0 permissions to

crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 4, 0 Jan 17 12:08 /dev/tty0

and 

Add your userid to the tty group.

Something like sudo useradd -G tty danielm;logout